# Create a single dataset out of X_train and Y_train

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an image dataset as X_train and its corresponding labels as Y_train in a separate csv file, How to add labels to X_train from Y_train?

I  have tried

```
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

dataset = data_utils.TensorDataset(data2, labels)
```

but this gives me an error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

whole traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/8j/rq8080716fbgz8ngr42t9zdr0000gn/T/ipykernel_21295/2155854144.py in <module>
      1 import torch.utils.data as data_utils
      2 
----> 3 dataset = data_utils.TensorDataset(data2, labels)
      4 train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=7, shuffle=True)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in __init__(self, *tensors)
    255 
    256     def __init__(self, *tensors: Tensor) -> None:
--> 257         assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
    258         self.tensors = tensors
    259 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    255 
    256     def __init__(self, *tensors: Tensor) -> None:
--> 257         assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
    258         self.tensors = tensors
    259 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: where does it give you this error? is this the whole traceback you are getting?

Comment: I have added the whole traceback.

Comment: what is `data2` and `labels`? where is it defined?

Comment: X_train.csv is loaded with np.loadtxt as data2, similarly Y_train is loaded as labels.

Comment: you need to put the relevant code for the question. Your problem is that either data2 or labels is an integer instead of a numpy array.

Comment: I checked, both the classes. They are numpy array.

Comment: Also, I can see the error size mismatch between tensors. Any idea how to go ahead with rectifying that?

Comment: each data point must have an associated label, if the sizes mismatch you need to understand why they mismatch. there's no magic formula, you have to check your data an correct it. it looks like what you have inside your numpy array are integers, but they must be tensors (which are like vectors and are iterable)